# SQL Two sets in an IF

Tags: sql, if-statement

Currently on a project for work and I am struggling a little with the Syntax, been working with basic SQL for about a year now.

my problem is the code I am writing looks untidy I am trying to tidy it up a bit.

i have two Variables one called `@NCDLLV` and one called `@PAFTER`

This is my current set of code

```
IF (@TRPREM > 1000 AND @NCDRP <> 'A')
Begin
IF @NCDRP = 'B' Set @NCDLLV = 10
IF @NCDRP = 'C' Set @NCDLLV = 20
IF @NCDRP = 'D' Set @NCDLLV = 30
IF @NCDRP = 'E' Set @NCDLLV = 40
End


IF @NCDRP = 'B' Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * 0.9
IF @NCDRP = 'C' Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * 0.8
IF @NCDRP = 'D' Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * 0.7
IF @NCDRP = 'E' Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * 0.6
```

however in practice at the moment my code runs two sets of IF's one setting the `@NCDLLV` and one setting `@PAFTER`.

i'm looking to condense this all into something a little shorter,

is there a way of doing this other than writing

```
IF @NCDRP = 'B'
Begin
Set @NCDLLV = 40
Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * 0.9
END
```

Thank you for your time

Kind Regards,

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Take a look at case expressions. Or case statements.

Comment: @jarlh Currently using a DBMS called Websure, im fairly new at this so unsure as to which version of SQL we use here, don't really have anyone to as either as i'm the only person in the IT department

Comment: I tried to search the RDBMS for "Websure", but came up empty. I did find a company that does "enterprise software solutions". But I find it odd that they should have made their own RDBMS. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @scratte sorry about that, im a junior at this firm but the only member of the IT team , we use a system called websure to handle all of our data, it is designed by that company you found in the google search, i am unsure as to what it is ran on behind the scenes and which versions of SQL we use to run sections of code like the above. the only people that i could ask would be the support line of that company, i appreciate your help, covering myself a little here encase, our website makes it known that we use websure :) kind regards,

Comment: What does `select @@version;` give you?

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like the below

```
IF (@TRPREM > 1000 AND @NCDRP <> 'A')
Begin
Set @NCDLLV =Case When  @NCDRP = 'B' Then 10  When @NCDRP = 'C' Then 20 When @NCDRP = 'D' Then 30 When @NCDRP = 'E' Then 40 End 
End

Set @PAFTER = @TRPREM * (Case When  @NCDRP = 'B' Then 0.9  When @NCDRP = 'C' Then 0.8 When @NCDRP = 'D' Then 0.7 When @NCDRP = 'E' Then 0.6 End )
```